# WPF live charts x axis labels are coming twice though set only once

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, livecharts

I m facing a issue in viewing the label list properly in x-axis while using livecharts in wpf.
The label list is proper, and before setting I clear the axis too.

The code used is:

```cs
EMT_Chart.AxisX.Clear();

int stepSize = 1;

Axis xAxis = new Axis()
{
    FontSize = 12,
    Separator = new LiveCharts.Wpf.Separator { Step = stepSize, IsEnabled = false },
    ShowLabels = true,
    Labels = labelList,
    LabelsRotation = -90.0
};
EMT_Chart.AxisX.Add(xAxis);
```

And xaml is as below:

```xml
<lvc:CartesianChart x:Name="EMT_Chart" 
                    Series="{Binding Series}" 
                    LegendLocation="Bottom" 
                    Zoom="XY" Pan="XY"/>
```

Basically on zooming out, the x-axis labels are coming in a cyclic fashion which isnt intended. And on zoominf in the value and label alignment gets messed up.

Please suggest.

This is the plot without zoom or pan

[image]

On zooming out the plot x-axis labels and the plot too doesn't look proper

[image]

On zooming in the plot x-axis labels and the values are not aligned

[image]